# How to replace \" with " in string columns scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, replace

I have a column of badly formatted nested json string that I'm trying to edit with `regexp_replace`. So that the column can be read by scala as a struct. There are random `\"` added to each item in the Json that i want to replace with `"`

```
{
{"id": "1", "json": [
{ \"details\": {\n \"name\" : \"john\", \n \"lastname\" : \"doe"\ \n},
\"location\": {\n  \"city\" : \"new york\", \n \"country\" : \"usa\" \n} },
{ \"details\": {\n \"name\" : \"jane\", \n \"lastname\" : \"random"\ \n},
\"location\": {\n  \"city\" : \"new york\", \n \"country\" : \"usa\" \n} },
] },
{"id": "2", "json": [
{ \"details\": {\n \"name\" : \"jack\", \n \"lastname\" : \"ryan"\ \n},
\"location\": {\n  \"city\" : \"york\", \n \"country\" : \"uk\" \n} },
{ \"details\": {\n \"name\" : \"jill\", \n \"lastname\" : \"test"\ \n},
\"location\": {\n  \"city\" : \"LA\", \n \"country\" : \"usa\" \n} },
] }
}
```

I was able to remove the `\n` with `regexp_replace` but i'm struggling with the `\"` wrapping each item.

```
var newdf = df.withcolumn( "clean_json",
  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col("json"), "\n", ""), """\"""", "\\\""))
```

I've tried using both `\\\` and `"""` as escape characters. nothing seems to work

Comment: So... what you have shared here.. this whole thing is the json string, right ? Is this in a file ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with regexp_replace nor am I able to reproduce your overall setup, but here is an example for replacing `\"` by `"` in plain scala: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ggy9AgbNSOuScuc8cCT2YA

Comment: @sarveshseri yes it's a file. I'm able to read and write the file. I'm trying to make the string column into json so that I can flatten. But I need to clean up first.

Comment: @MartinHH i tried using the method in the link. regex.replaceAllIn() doesn't work with columns.

Comment: @Ponle Well, my point was: `""""(\\\")"""` (as regex) and `"\""` (as replacement) are scala string parameters that work for the "plain scala" way, so I guess they would also work in `regexp_replace(col("json"), """(\\\")""", "\"")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace `\`, you should replace with `\\\\`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(['\\"'], StringType()).toDF('value')
df.withColumn('new_value', f.regexp_replace('value', '\\\\"', '')).show(truncate=False)

+-----+---------+
|value|new_value|
+-----+---------+
|\"   |         |
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace `\"` with a single double quote `"`

Comment: then add " to the example.